# Error Downloading rosemacs

Tags: ros, git, download

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I was trying to install rosemacs an I get this error just when I'm trying to downoload the git stack.

```
$ git clone https://kforge.ros.org/rosemacs/git rosemacs
Cloning into rosemacs...
error: gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received. while accessing https://kforge.ros.org/rosemacs/git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I have checked the web page https://kforge.ros.org/rosemacs/git and it exist but I can't do the clone

Any suggestion ?
The problem is from my computer or from the rosemacs repository ?

Thanks in advance,

Arnau

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30556/error-downloading-rosemacs/) by [Catotaku](https://answers.ros.org/users/516/catotaku/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-03-27**:
Maybe your git version is too old? What's the output of git --version?

**Comment by [Catotaku](https://answers.ros.org/users/516/catotaku/) on 2012-03-28**:
my git version is:
git version 1.7.5.4

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-03-28**:
Ok. Mine is 1.7.0.4. So maybe yours is too new? :) If nothing works, check out rosemacs from https://github.com/moesenle/rosemacs-debs.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks to be a problem with your computer.  Look for firewalls and proxies.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0